# Change the specific value in a localStorage Object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, local-storage

I have a piece of code that is supposed to search a JSON array in localStorage and modify the `isTaken` value inside the specific "equipment" (for example I'm trying to take a 250ml Flask so I enter the equipment name "250ml flask" and I modify the isTaken value of that flask to `true`)

JSON is formatted as such:

```
equipmentdata = [
   {
      "id":1649778788049,
      "name":"500ml Flask",
      "type":"Flask",
      "isTaken":false,
      "dateAdded":"Tue, 12 Apr 2022 15:53:00 GMT"
   },
   {
      "id":1649778800655,
      "name":"250ml Flask",
      "type":"Flask",
      "isTaken":false,
      "dateAdded":"Tue, 12 Apr 2022 15:53:00 GMT"
   },
   {
      "id":1649778809178,
      "name":"Measuring Cylinder",
      "type":"mesCyl",
      "isTaken":false,
      "dateAdded":"Tue, 12 Apr 2022 15:53:00 GMT"
   }
]
```

My JS is as follows,

```
function takeHandler() {
        const date = new Date();
        let finalD = date.toUTCString();
        let teachName = document.getElementById("name").value;
        let equipmentName = document.getElementById("eqname").value;
        let output = teachName + " took " + equipmentName + " at " + finalD;

        localStorage.setItem("equipmentTaken", null);
        
        var eqhis = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("equipmentTaken")) || [];
        eqhis.push(output)
        localStorage.setItem("equipmentTaken", JSON.stringify(eqhis));
        
        let finalout = localStorage.getItem("equipmentTaken");

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = finalout;

        var currentData = localStorage.getItem("equipmentdata");
        currentData = currentData ? JSON.parse(currentData) : {};
        currentData[eqname, isTaken] = true;
}
```

The main error is the the last line, I'm not really good at javascript and I cant really get the "eqname" value from the JSON and replace its "isTaken" value with `true`

my expected output would look like this

```
{
      "id":1649778800655,
      "name":"250ml Flask",
      "type":"Flask",
      "isTaken":true,
      "dateAdded":"Tue, 12 Apr 2022 15:53:00 GMT"
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it was tested and working properly

```
var currentData = localStorage.getItem("equipmentdata");
currentData = currentData ? JSON.parse(currentData) : {};

updateIsTaken(currentdata,"250ml Flask");

 localStorage.setItem("equipmentdata", currentdata);


function updateIsTaken(equipment, name)
{
  equipment.forEach(item => {
    if(item.name==name)
    {
      item.isTaken=true;
    }
  });
}
```

And I don't know how to you keep data in a local storage, so maybe you don't need to parse.

Comment: this didn't really work, it just replaces the entire array with the function updateIsTaken as a string. no actual code runs.

Comment: @EmberBaban25  Sorry, It had a typo, try again

Comment: hmm now the output is [object Object],[object Object]. which is weird since in the debugger it functions properly until the localStorage.setItem part after which it just disregards the function call

Comment: @EmberBaban25 try this  updateIsTaken(currentdata,"250ml Flask"); console.log(JSON.stringify(currentdata));

Comment: now the output functions however the array stored in localstorage is still converted into [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @EmberBaban25 As I told I don't know what format are you using. Try this localStorage.setItem("equipmentdata",  JSON.stringify(currentdata));

Answer (score 0):

Invalid syntax.

```js
// Invalid assignment, this doesn't work in javascript. We need the key as a string
currentData[eqname, isTaken] = true;

// Should be
currentData['eqname'] = true;
currentData['isTaken'] = true;

// As a oneliner, assign object directly. Here we don't need string flaps
currentData = { eqname: true, isTaken: true }
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work as I'm trying to change the isTaken value of the equipment matching the name eqname. so my expected output would be `"name":"250ml Flask",
      "type":"Flask",
      "isTaken":true,`
and everything else would stay the same.

Comment: Oh. You're trying to edit the array?  
Loop through a filter and change value then.  
`currentData.filter(x => x.name === equipmentName).map(y => y.isTaken = true)`
Vanilla loop would be  

`for(let item of currenData){  
  if(item.name yada yada)  
}`